# how to copy a DataGridView's content inside another

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`, said `dgA`. This contains some informations that I need to copy in another `DataGridView` said `dgB` as soon buttons `btn` is clicked.

How can I do this in Visual Basic?

Comment: Are the columns in both datagridviews the same? Is the DataGridView bound to a datasource?

Comment: Yes completly identical. DataGrid is bounded to a DataSource, but it's internal to another subroutine and I wouldn't make it global.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the data source of dgA (Being a DataTable for example), and bind dgB to it aswell. You should get the same data source on the 2 grids.

Example:

```
Dim dtSource As New DataTable
' Configure your source here...

' Bind first grid
    dgA.DataSource = dtSource
    dgA.DataBind()

' Use same data source for this grid...
    dgB.DataSource = dgA.DataSource
    dgB.DataBind()
```

You can then alter the configuration of how the grid appears from the .ASPX. You can also use a session, to be used in different pages.

Comment: DataSource is internal to another subroutine and I wouldn't make it global.

Comment: Maybe store it in a session? i.e You get a data source, store it in a session, and this session would be used for the other grid? Obviously assuming that dgA loads first.

Answer (score 1):

### Non-Databound DataGridView

Why not go through each row of your `DataGridView1` (*dgA*) and send the cell values to `DataGridView2` (*dgB*)?

I added two columns to my DataGridViews, so apply this code respectively to your datagridview columns.

```
Private Sub CopyDgv1ToDgv2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CopyDgv1ToDgv2.Click
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgA.Rows
        If r.IsNewRow Then Continue For

        'r.Cells(0).Value is the current row's first column, r.Cells(1).Value is the second column
        dgB.Rows.Add({r.Cells(0).Value, r.Cells(1).Value})
    Next
End Sub
```

This goes through each row of my first `DataGridView` and adds a row in my second `DataGridView` with the values contained in the first `DataGridView`.

---

### DataBoundDataGridView

If the data is bound on both `DataGridViews` then all you need to do is copy the data source to the other DataGridView like so:

```
Private Sub CopyDgv1ToDgv2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CopyDgv1ToDgv2.Click
    dgB.DataSource = dgA.DataSource
End Sub
```

Comment: I see... I thought only the first DataGridView was bound to a datasource. Both must be bound in that case.